# Does 'automatic' automation exist or when will it?

Tags: selenium, automation, angularjs-e2e

I've been using selenium and protractor to write end to end test cases for a while now. Is there such program that records mouse and keyboard movements that can 'record' which web elements have been clicked and reproduce to make 'user like' movements and automatically create test cases based on a users movements? If it does exist could someone provide me with details. If it doesn't exist.. I guarantee that it is a worthy investment for the future of automation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Selenium IDE?
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

There are numerous commercial solutions like Testcomplete, IBM Rational Functional Tester, HP UFT and lot more.